# Using php how I check a pdf file contents is valid or invalid

Tags: php, regex, validation, pdf

I am trying to implement a functionality that should be to detect pdf file and it's content is valid or invalid. Using following scripts I can easily detect whether file is pdf or not:

```
  $info = pathinfo("test.pdf");
  if ($info["extension"] == "pdf"){
  echo "PDF file";
  }
```

Now I want to check if a file extension pdf then content of pdf file should be valid.

Please tell how can I check pdf file contents are valid not corrupted or invalid format.

Comment: You could try [FPDI](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/the-fpdi-class/#index-3-1) and see if that function returns 0 pages if the file is invalid.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Content of pdf file start with **%PDF**-version no, So at first get contents of pdf file using following scripts:

```
$filecontent = file_get_contents("test.pdf");
```

After that check **$filecontent** variable using following regular expression in order detect it's valid or invalid format:

```
if (preg_match("/^%PDF-1.5/", $filecontent)) {
    echo "Valid pdf";
} else {
    echo "In Valid pdf";
}
```

**Note:** Pdf version could be different such 1.0 , 1.5 , 1.7 etc... In my case it was 1.5 also make sure you have placed above code inside of scripts/conditions (if file has **.pdf** extension).

Comment: This merely is a plausibility check, magic bytes style. It will recognise if you e.g. feed it a words document but it does not check whether the pdf is valid. It seems to suffice for the op, though.

Comment: I left the version out so the PDF version could be any number.       `preg_match("/^%PDF-/", $filecontent)`

Comment: Note that the `else` case could be removed if you would use ar return statement in the `if`.

Comment: I'd suggest you also check if the content matches "%%EOF\v*$"
That way, you are sure you somehow didn't get half a PDF file (interrupted download, or what not)

Comment: @danielklejnstrup mentions a good point about the "%%EOF". We have had our site tested for penetration, and the company successfully uploaded a file that was **named** with a PDF extension, and **included** the "%PDF-" at the beginning. After that header was a PHP script ready to fire up some nasties. But didn't happen to have the "%%EOF". That may not be a foolproof guarantee there is no shell or other executable script hiding inside the file, but every test is another step towards safety.

Answer (score 3):

I use [FPDI](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI) to create and import existing pdf files.
When the pdf file is invalid, an error will be thrown: Unable to find PDF file header.;
Will pass when the pdf is valid.

It's working fine for me so far.

```
try {
    $pdf = new \setasign\Fpdi\Tcpdf\Fpdi();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->setSourceFile($filepath);
    $pdf->_destroy();
    return true;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    debug('Pdf validation failed. error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    return false;
}
```

---

I found out that when parsing pdf files with Fpdi, you have to use their commercial version.

Its commercial version may work just fine.

But we finally adopted the method of modifying the file header to prevent XSS attacks.
When we upload pdf to aws S3, set:

```
'ContentType' => 'application/octet-stream'
```

In this way, when we access this PDF file through the URL, it will be downloaded by default instead of opening it directly.

In the same way, when uploading to your own server, you can also use a similar approach.

In addition, by applying WAF of aws, XSS attacks in PDF can also be intercepted.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can create PDF files using the built-in libraries [Haru](http://php.net/manual/en/book.haru.php) and [PDF](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php), but cannot directly read, parse or validate PDF files. You will need an external library or tool for this. You can look into [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) but it seems to be a Windows-only solution which is probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: pdftk is available as a command-line tool for linux - part of the main debian repository.
So you should be able to execute pdftk from php, if you have sufficient permissions for that.

Comment: There is also a Linux command-line tool called "qpdf". Using such a tool to verify the incoming file is probably as close to foolproof as is possible. PDF headers and footers are good steps, but you still need something to verify what is in between.